# How would I modify this method so I can reference or pass the data of each individual loop?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how to go about referencing each loop of data so that I can pass it to a textbox.
If there are 5 loops, how can I choose ONLY the 3rd loop to display in a textbox on my main form?
I've added m_intNumberofEvents to count the number of loops it does but I don't know how to connect it or if it even works. Please help! Thank you!

```
public List<Event> ExtractData(DateTime dtmDay)
{
     int intChosenDay = dtmDay.Day;
     m_intNumberofEvents = 0;
     int intFileDay;

     StreamReader textIn = new StreamReader(
         new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read));

     //create the list
     List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

     for (int index = 4; index < lines.Length; index += 5)
     {
        Event special = new Event();
        special.Day = Convert.ToInt32(lines[index - 4]);
        special.Time = (lines[index - 3]);
        special.Price = Convert.ToDouble(lines[index - 2]);
        special.StrEvent = lines[index - 1];
        special.Description = lines[index];
        events.Add(special);
        m_intNumberofEvents++;
     }
     textIn.Close();
     return events;
  }
```

Comment: "5 loops" is generally not good, you might consider refactoring your code!

Comment: In theory, it could be 100 loops depending on the size of the text file.

Comment: @Jae Just to clarify, loops or iterations? I am really confused what you mean. I see only one loop in given code and on runtime they wont be added (at least in normal environment they should not).

Comment: @Jae I assume you mean iterations, not loops as in for loops?

Comment: Ummm...each time the for loop is repeated = 1 "loop". SO, the first 5 lines of a text file is 1 set. The 2nd 5 lines of the text file is the 2nd set. I'd like to be able to grab whichever SET I want and have it display in a text box.

Comment: Do you also need the other 4 Events? or you only need to grab a specific `Event` from the text file?

Comment: No `using` on Stream, no input validation, hardcoded "set" size, useless variable `m_intNumberofEvents`. Your code is going to be error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong in your requirement, but after the loop you will have a list of `Event` objects, if you just want to use the 3rd item (i.e. the one populated in the 3rd loop) then you can pull it from the list like so:

```
Event thridEvent = events[2];//NOTE: 0 based index
//do something with the event, like populate a textbox
```

You can access any item in the list you want, 0 = 1st, 1 = 2nd, 2 = 3rd, etc...

You also don't need to count the number of loops it does, you can get the same value from the length of the list:

```
int numberOfLoops = events.Count();
```

It is also worth mentioning that you have no validation on your input file, if the input data is not in the expected format your application will crash.

Comment: That helps alot! But now I am running into a different issue...this is my combobox's selectedIndexChanged event....private void cboEvent_SelectedIndexChanged( 
         object sender, System.EventArgs e )
      {
         Event numberofevents = events[mvwDate_DateChanged];
         txtDescription.Text = Convert.ToString(numberofevents);
      }

Comment: @Jae: ...and what is the problem with it? If this is not related to this question, then you need to either try and solve it yourself, or ask a new question

Comment: I have an error highlighting the "events[mvwDate_DateChanged] part. It says "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TicketInformation.Event>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments." Not sure where/what the invalid arguments would be....

Comment: @Jae: `mvwDate_DateChanged` needs to be an `int`, I suspect that is the problem

Comment: Hmm okay. One last question please. If I want to reference special.Day of events[3], how would I write that so that I may pass the integer value in special.Day ?

Comment: I will ask a separate question on how to reference special.Day of events[3]. Thanks for your help musefan!

Answer (score 0):

You could extract your logic into a separate method to simplify extracting the Event objects from the string[] array:

```
Event ReadEventFromIndex(string[] lines, int index)
{
    index = 4 + index * 5;
    Event special = new Event();
    special.Day = Convert.ToInt32(lines[index - 4]);
    special.Time = (lines[index - 3]);
    special.Price = Convert.ToDouble(lines[index - 2]);
    special.StrEvent = lines[index - 1];
    special.Description = lines[index];     

    return special;
}
```

Note how I convert the logical index to the offset required for accessing `lines[]` by doing `index = 4 + index * 5;`

Then if you want, say, the 3rd item (which will be at logical index 2, not 3 of course) you could just do:

```
var thirdEvent = ReadEventFromIndex(lines, 2);
```

Comment: Is that a 2 dimension array? The original problem uses 2 dimensional array to grab the text data of which I am trying to convert using a list...

Comment: @Jae By "original problem" do you mean some code you didn't post in your question? Because there are no 2D arrays in the code you posted... The code I posted in the answer above returns an individual Event for the specified index; there are no 2D arrays in it.

Comment: Yes, I'm not too familiar with index's. Is the data still loaded into the list? When you say if I want the 3rd item, do you mean the 3rd set of data(day,time,price,strevent,description)? Is there a way to retrieve just "special.Day" from the 3rd set?